# Applying for second masters/Which GPA matters most?

Tags: masters

I have an MA in Education and I've been teaching for 9 years at a community college. I decided to continue teaching but obtain graduate credits in another discipline. I have wanted to change from developmental to another discipline for some time. Which GPA will admissions committee most likely consider, undergrad or grad? My undergrad isn't so great, but I have a 4.0 grad school gpa. No scores were required for program.

Answer (score 1):

A masters admissions committee will be interested in your grades in the highest level coursework that prepared you for the master's program you are applying for.  You did not say what discipline you are seeking a degree in.  Your teaching experience should count for more than your past course work, if you are teaching in a related area.